# how to show my image using rails and carrierwave in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

im buiding some app with image but it doesnt show

im using linux

<%= image_tag @articles.avatar_url %>

NoMethodError in Articles#index

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". Take a look at your question. If a peer handed you a piece of paper with that printed on it what would you ask them to show you? We need enough code to replicate the problem, along with any necessary input and the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

move to active storage instead here are the guides you need:
https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html
https://gorails.com/episodes/direct-uploads-with-rails-active-storage?autoplay=1